# How to bring a navigation bar in front of view

Tags: ios, swift, cometchat

I am working on an App in which clicking on message icon in navigation bar in one view segues to other view where `CometChat` extension is used.

However when I go to the other view my entire navigation bar is hidden and all i see is the `Cometchat` on all the view.

I've tried to add a button by going through code in `Cometchat` UI kit but without luck. So is there any way I can make my nav bar visible or anything what I can use to return to the app?

[The storyboard with Message View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGKyB.png)

[The Cometchat embedded view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMUV5.png)

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example